# How can I "touch" one component from another without nesting?

Tags: reactjs, components

Given this component tree:

```
c0 - c11 - c12 - c13
   \
     c21 - c22
```

What is the best way to send some data from c13 to c22 ?

In my case I had something like forum page(c0): there were message feed (c11), message (c12), "quote" button (c13) and block with some controls (c21) including message form (c22).

What I wanted is to add some text to message form on quotation click.
So I added callback (via prop) onQuote to message that is just being called with message text (with some transformations) like this: `this.props.onQuote(txt)`. Then I provided it from root component (c0) via passing it in a chain: c0 - c11 - c12. And since text in message form is kept in c22 state I had to create method like `.setText(txt)` and create delegation from c21 to call it from c0.

This looks pretty bad (another word, actually) and complicated (too much code) to me.

How would I do better? I don't wanna use global state and I don't believe that this is the react way to do things. I don't really like the whole "passing" thing when there're many components in the middle that do nothing with data but just pass it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The preferred and proposed method by Facebook itself is to lift up state to at least to the nearest common ancestor of both components.

Comment: Well, I dont like "lift up state" solution in this case, because it's too much coupling in containers. Why would I keep typed text in some container and pass it through 3 components instead of just keeping it in MessageForm component?

Comment: Beacause this is how React is intended to work by its authors - https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html - so or you are very skilled or may be you are wasting your time